How can I change the bed temperature after 3-4 layers instead of first layer?
I just bought my first printer QIDI Q1 Pro and it's great. The problem I face now is that when I print PLA, my printer just constantly gets jammed because PLA just melts down even before it comes to the nozzle so the printer can not pull down the PLA string. I realize that if the air temperature inside the printer goes over 42 °C for a long time, this starts to happen. May be because I live in a hot country and the daily temperature in my room is about 37-38 °C. Knowing so little about slicing settings, I installed a little fan outside the printer to cool down the temperature and now printing works well.
Searching a little bit, I know that PLA can be printed even without bed temperature and Orcaslicer has a setting that can change the bed temperature after the fist layer so I wonder if there is any way to set the bed temperature to turn off after three layers instead of just first layer to maintain adhesion better but still keep the air cool?
I am totally new so please explain and guide me a little more details if it goes to G-code or something too advanced.

Within OrcaSlicer click the "pencil and pad" to edit your printer preset (indicated by the blue arrow in the image), enable Advanced in the preset window (indicated by the green arrow), then click the Machine G-code tab at the top. Scroll down to the Layer Change G-code pane and enter this code after any code already present:
{if (filament_type[0] == "PLA" and layer_num == 4)}M140 S0; Tool 0 is loaded with PLA, so turning off bed heat after 3 layers.{endif}

...and close the window to save.

This G-code tests if the chosen filament is PLA, and if so it turns off the bed when the print job reaches layer 4 (and print continues, it does not wait for the bed to cool). I've tested on PrusaSlicer and OrcaSlicer.
